# Территория, террорист, террариум, терраса, терракота - Какие слова близки по происхождению?

Tags: этимология

Территория, террорист, террариум, терраса, терракота. Какие из слов имеют общее происхождение?

Answer (score 4):

*Территория, террариум, терраса, терракота* -- от лат. слова "терра" -- земля, почва, суша.
*Террорист* -- от лат. "terror, terrere" — пугать, ужасать, запугивать.